# Can not find cakephp model

Tags: php, cakephp, frameworks

I am having extreme issues trying to get cakephp to find a model. i been working on this project for 4 months now and created ton's of models but for some reason, cake can not find this model. This is how it is set up at minimum

**app/controllers/arbitrations_controller.php**

```
<?php
class ArbitrationsController extends AppController {
    var $name = 'Arbitrations';        
}
```

**app/models/arbitration.php**

```
<?php
class Arbitration extends AppModel {
    var $name = 'Arbitration';
}
```

**database name: arbitrations**

**Error Message**

> Controller::paginate() - can't find model Arbitration in controller
>   ArbitrationsController [CORE\cake\libs\controller\controller.php, line
>   1102]

I've tried clearing `tmp/cache/models` and `tmp/cache/persistent`

Comment: try cleaning out every single folder in `/app/tmp` and running the code again

Comment: is `$this->Arbitration` defined (in your controller)?

Comment: have you make those files controller, model by your self or via console? if you have made those files manually try creating them with console.

Comment: @MarekSebera I tried that several times. What i did is I went into `tmp/cache/models` and cleared everything in it as well as `tmp/cache/persisten`

Comment: @Ehtesham I have not tried the console. I could give it a try. I just hope this doesnt happen from here on out

Comment: I don't know Cake, but given the code you've shown, I can't see how the controller can know what the model is called. Is there maybe some template code you've not supplied?

Comment: What version of cakephp are you running? The code looks like 1.3, but it changes with 2.0 and higher. That's why I want to confirm.

Comment: What is strange is I have the modeling being called in another controller by association and it works. but in the controller it self, its not detecting the model

Answer (score 1):

I got it to work. I just deleted my arbitrations_controller.php file and recreated and it worked. Must be some type of glitch or something. I think it may have had something to do with even going about deleting the tmp files and recreating the files again.

Dont know what it was, but it wasted 3 hours of my life.

Comment: Glad to hear. It could have very easily been misspelled somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

I just set this up using CakePHP v1.3.x and it worked out of the box using scaffolding. A couple of things you can try:

1. Double check the spelling on everything. Arbitration can be easily
   misspelled.
2. Add the `var $uses = array('Arbitration')` to the top of the
   controller and see if that changes anything.
3. Double check the model spellings in the controller
   `$this->Arbitration->recursive = -1;`

If all of those things are set and working as expected it should work. Another thing to try is to load it in a clean app to see if it works in a stand alone environment.